# Reuse EWS connection and negotiate authentication for Exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am writing a program to dump the contents of numerous mailboxes from an Exchange server using EWS in C#.  Using fiddler I noticed that each request I send makes a new connection (tunnel), with a new authentication process being undertaken (using negotiate). My ServerCertificateValidationCallback gets called for every request.

If I enable the option in Fiddler to "reuse server connections" than the connection is only created during handshaking, and is re-used for all requests (saving lots of time).

By getting the EWS source and modifying the requests I found if I enable "UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing" on the request objects than the connection is re-used (extra tunnels & ServerCertificateValidationCallbacks disappear), but each request still requires the full handshake authentication.  This is because the server sends back a 401 when ever I try and use the exchange cookie.

**Is there any way I can re-use my server connection & authentication?**

```
public class EwsExchange
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        sslCertCheckCount = 0;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ServerCertificateValidation;

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(args[1], args[2]);
        service.Url = new Uri(args[0] + @"/EWS/exchange.asmx");
        service.KeepAlive = true;
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;
        //service.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;

        Folder folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new PropertySet(FolderSchema.Id, FolderSchema.DisplayName));
        FindItemsResults<Item> res = folder.FindItems(new ItemView(int.MaxValue));

        return 0;
    }

    public static bool ServerCertificateValidation(Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" ****************** ServerCertificateValidation - count: {0}. ****************** ", ++sslCertCheckCount));
        return true;
    }

    static int sslCertCheckCount;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome! You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already, and I'd recommend to read how to provide a [clear and minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Your code is quite long, and havign a minimal example would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that after I modified the EWS API to allow me to enable UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing on the HttpRequests, that my connection and authentication were actually being re-used.

Fiddler was the one dropping my connections after I disabled the option "Tools -> Fiddler Options -> Connections ->  Reuse server connections".  Running wireshark on the exchange server machine showed that when fiddler was capturing with this option disabled the FIN TCP flag was being set, ending the session.   But without fiddler capturing the connection & session were both re-used.